# Unnest a records column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering if there is a `pandas` way (in-built, or generally better) to unnest a column of records (where records are `List[dict]`) into a `DataFrame`.

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd


expected = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, 2],
    'asset_id': ["aaa", "AAA", "bbb"],
    'another_prop': [2, 3, 4]
})

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1,2],
    'B':[
            [
                {"asset_id": "aaa", "another_prop": 2}, 
                {"asset_id": "AAA", "another_prop": 4}
            ],
            [
                {"asset_id": "bbb", "another_prop": 3}
            ]
        ]
    })
```

My attempt:

```
def unnest_records(df: pd.DataFrame, col: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """ Unnests a column of records into a DataFrame."""
    df_unnested = df.explode(col)  # unnest records
    records = df_unnested.pop(col)  # 1 row per record
    return pd.concat([df_unnested.reset_index(drop=True), pd.io.json.json_normalize(records)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> unnest_records(df, "B")
   A asset_id  another_prop
0  1      aaa             2
1  1      AAA             4
2  2      bbb             3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC `explode` `pd.Series` and `set_index`

```
df1 = df.set_index('A')['B'].explode().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()

   A asset_id  another_prop
0  1      aaa             2
1  1      AAA             4
2  2      bbb             3
```

or as @anky so kindly pointed out :

```
s = df['B'].explode()
df = df[['A']].join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index))

print(df)
   A asset_id  another_prop
0  1      aaa             2
0  1      AAA             4
1  2      bbb             3
```

Comment: `s=df.set_index('A')['B'].explode()` and `pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index).reset_index()` should be able to get rid of the apply pd.Series

Comment: @anky - Is there a reason to prefer not using the `apply`?

Comment: @AkhilNair only if your data is large  , apply(pd.Series) is slow

Answer (score 2):

Another option using itertools:

```
from itertools import chain

pd.DataFrame(chain(*df.B))
```

Comment: Nice - Is there a clean way to stitch it back to the original table?

Comment: Well, what would go where? Could you show how you'd like it to look?

Comment: Expected result is in the original question - when I run you solution it is missing column "A" in `expected`

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen it's good but you lose the index number when you chain so you don't know what row belongs to what ID

Comment: Right, didn't think of that! Go with @Datanovice